# Any type of scope resolution operator in Python?

Tags: python

Is there any way to make the python interpreter choose the global variable specifically when there is also a local variable with the same name? (Like C++ has :: operator)

```
x=50

def fun():
    x=20
    print("The value of local x is",x)

    global x
    #How can I display the value of global x here?
    print("The value of global x is",x)

print("The value of global x is",x)
fun()
```

The second print statement inside the function block should display the value of global x.

```
File "/home/karthik/PycharmProjects/helloworld/scope.py", line 7

global x
^

SyntaxError: name 'x' is used prior to global declaration

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Use a different name for the local variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python does not have a direct equivalent to the `::` operator (typically that kind of thing is handled by the dot `.`). To access a variable from an outer scope, assign it to a different name as to not shadow it:

```
x = 50

def fun():
    x = 20
    print(x)  # 20

    print(x_)  # 50

print(x)  # 50
x_ = x
fun()
```

But of course Python would not be Python if there weren't a hack around this... What you describe is actually possible, but I do not recommend it:

```
x = 50

def fun():
    x = 20
    print(x)  # 20

    print(globals()['x'])  # 50

print(x)  # 50
fun()
```

Comment: So, basically, the globals() method lists out all elements of the global symbol table loaded by the compiler. So, we are accessing and changing one of the elements there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to do this (and I am not an expert). The two solutions that I can think of are to give another name to your `local x` (like `xLoc`), or to put your `global x` in argument, like this :

```
x=50

def fun(xGlob):
    x=20
    print("The value of local x is",x)

    print("The value of global x is",xGlob)

print("The value of global x is",x)
fun(x)
```

Is this answering your question ?